# centos linux log messages filling up with page not found

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, drupal

We have experienced some instability on our server lately. Checking log/messages there is a lot of messages like this

```
Apr 25 20:27:17 lillevinkel2 drupal: http://skobloggen.lillevinkelsko.no|1335378437|page not found|122.232.5.21|http://skobloggen.lillevinkelsko.no/http://www.magicptp.com/promote.php?id=dongxh|http://pulsreklamy.pl/|0||promote.php
```

They are from a lot of different ip adresses. I added in .htaccess that everything with http in should be denied. pasting the url from the log results in access denied in browser, but the log is still filling with this. What can I do to prevent this kind of spidering or stop the requests before they result in a page not found?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a matter of the logs filling up, you can stop logging those entries using SetEnvIf.  Something like:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "http" NoLog
CustomLog logs/access_log common env=!NoLog
```

More documentation here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_setenvif.html and
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/env.html

Comment: That will clean up the log and is very useful. Thx. But I would also like to stop it with "access denied" before there is a "page not found". My access denied rewrite  rule works when I paste the URL into the browser, but still it is coming new "page not found" messages.

Comment: Look at: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html#env You can do a similar `Deny from env=NoLog` with the same `SetEnvIf` pattern match.